# Can I use the sails's query modifier "contains" with a collection of objects?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm trying to obtain all objects that have an especific object in a collection.
Example:

Object Company has a collection of Employees, and I want to find all Companies who have a especific Employee on this collection. What I'm trying to do is:

```js
Company.find({where:{employees: {contains: employeeX}}}, function (err, companies) {
  ...
});
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
var criteria = { "employees":{$in: [{employeeId:employeeXId}]}};     

User
   .find(criteria)  
   .then(function(data){
      //Employee Collection
   })
```

This works for me